# Setting two tabs to split view in one action when using safari macOS catalina

Tags: macos, safari, split-view

I'm using macOS Catalina 10.15.4 on a MacBook Pro 2018.

When using **safari browser** with two tabs in *Full Screen*, sometimes I want to drag one tab to view then side-by-side in split view.

The way I do it now is dragging one tab down from the tabs-bar, it opens in its own full screen view and then I drag them side-by-side just like:

[image]

I wonder if there is more efficient way to do it, requiring less actions (hopefully one darg or even keyboard shortcut).

Answer (score 1):

If you have two safari windows open (*command + n*) then you can press long on the green button on the top left of one of the two windows and the following window will appear:

[image]

Then you can choose where you want this page on your screen, left or right, and then on the other side where you selected you can choose the other safari pages. There are keyboard shortcuts for what I don't know ... But a little less expensive than your version

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. I'm actually farmiliar with that method. Unfortunately, it does not help in my case, since I wish to split (in one action) from the state of two **tabs** opened in **the same** window, to a split view of each tab opened in different side of the screen. Any ideas to solve that?

Comment: No I think you can't do this with a keyboard command ... but it is also possible with my solution: "pull the tab from the list, press the green button and select where you want it to be positioned (left, right)". You can do it how you want, just showed another way